# VB6 : error when calling .Open on an adodb.Connection object (works with specific contexts)

Tags: vb6, odbc

I'm currently working with small-size old VB6 application.

Here is my problem : when the user clicks a button, the program is opening a connection to an Oracle Database. This works good when running from the IDE or running the .exe in Windows 95 or Windows 98 compatibility modes, otherwise it crashes.
It does work on another workstation but I don't know why (different configuration but I have no idea what that could be !)

Here is the code called when the button is pressed (it works on another workstation which has no compatibility setting set but might have some other configuration differences).
Most of the code is not related to the connection but I have let it untouched for the sake of completeness.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
'
'   Loads the list of printers (as defined in a table of the SQL DB)
'
    On Error GoTo error_handler

    '   icon
    Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass


    'Dim conn As New adodb.Connection
    'Dim cmd As New adodb.Command
    'Dim rcs As New adodb.Recordset
    Dim conn As adodb.Connection
    Dim cmd As adodb.Command
    Dim rcs As adodb.Recordset

    Set conn = New adodb.Connection
    Set cmd = New adodb.Command
    Set rcs = New adodb.Recordset

    'Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fs As FileSystemObject
    Set fs = New FileSystemObject
    Dim fic As File
    Dim texte As textStream
    Dim req As String


    Dim i As Integer
    Dim chem As Variant

    Dim buffer As String
    Dim retstring As String
    Dim rc As Long

    If fs.FileExists(Appli_Rep & "Queries\System\printers_list.txt") Then
        Set fic = fs.GetFile(Appli_Rep & "Queries\System\printers_list.txt")
        Set texte = fic.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
    End If


    '
    '   Reads connection string
    '
    buffer = String(145, " ")
    rc = GetPrivateProfileString("Requete", "DRIVER", "1", buffer, Len(buffer) - 1, Appli_Rep & "suivi__.ini")
    DoEvents
    retstring = Left(buffer, InStr(buffer, Chr(0)) - 1)

    '
    '   Gets the PATH environment variable
    '   So that we know where to find tnsname.ora
    '
    i = 0
    chem = Split(Environ("TNS_ADMIN"), ";")
    Do
        If Len(Dir(chem(i) & "\Tnsnames.ora")) <> 0 Then
            ChDrive chem(i)
            ChDir chem(i)
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 1
        DoEvents
    Loop Until i > UBound(chem)


    ' Opens a connection (no DSN)

    'Set conn = New adodb.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "uid=_uid;pwd=_pwd;DRIVER=" & retstring & ";server=__PROD;"
    'conn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 3000    ' (no change)

    conn.Open   ' -2147467259 [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-06413: Connexion non ouverte
        ' Connexion non ouverte = french for "connection is closed".

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    cmd.CommandText = texte.ReadAll

    DoEvents

    Set texte = Nothing
    Set fic = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing

    Set rcs = cmd.Execute

    DoEvents

    rcs.MoveFirst

    Do
        Me.cbo_Imprimantes.AddItem (rcs.Fields("IMPRIMANTE").Value)
        rcs.MoveNext
        DoEvents
    Loop Until rcs.EOF

    '   Close connections / free objects
    Set rcs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    If conn.State = 1 Then
        conn.Close
    End If
    Set conn = Nothing

    '   icon back to normal
    Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

    Exit Sub

error_handler:

    '   retour normal
    Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Erreur !!!"
        MsgBox Err.Source
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    '   Fermeture des objets
    Set rcs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set texte = Nothing
    Set fic = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing



End Sub
```

It crashes on the "conn.Open" statement.
The connection string is identical in both cases (I have displayed it in a messagebox to be sure that 'retstring' is valid).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is any error info returned or logged when the crash occurs?

Comment: The error is catched by the error manager : MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Erreur !!!". Which displays a message box with the information I have added as a comment in the code : -2147467259 [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-06413: Connexion non ouverte. I haven't checked the ODBC logs yet, I'll try that.

Comment: Ok, to start with I'd say verify that the credentials for the username and password are valid; you might try connecting to the Oracle database using its query analyzer or similar tool with those credentials and see whether it allows that user to log in. Also you could check out the Oracle section on [this site](http://connectionstrings.com/oracle) to see whether the string itself needs to be updated or may be missing any info.

Comment: It is 100% sure the credentials are valid (because it works when executed from the IDE, and I use these credentials all day anyway).
For now I'll check the connection string nonetheless (can't hurt) and the logs, thank you.

Comment: Ok, here are the logs : http://pastebin.com/zJJE2VHy (executed from the IDE) and http://pastebin.com/952yXPhf. Some things to notice : the .exe version calls SQLFreeEnv, and calls SQLAllocEnv with a different thread ID from before (87c-129c instead of 88-123c).

Comment: Are you encountering this error when you run the .exe from a network drive under Windows Vista or higher?

Comment: I am running it under Windows XP. Yes, I am running it from a network drive. Since yesterday I have found out that in some cases App.Path will be a UNC path, and in some others, it will use the corresponding network drive letter, I have already tried copying it to a local directory first. It does not make a difference, the same error pops out.

Comment: I have had problems running VB6 applications from a network drive under Windows 7. They fail on some operations when you run them from a non trusted location, particularly connecting to databases. The only solution I found was to create a small program that copies the .exe and .ini to the Temp directory and run them locally.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the actual source of the problem, as I have tried copying the folder in D:\temp (I have also tried C:\temp and my desktop) and executing from there yesterday. The result is the same. It might have something to with user rights, though. The EXE running OK when compatibility mode is set to 95/98 is definitely fishy.

Comment: Ok I have found the origin of the problem (but not a full explanation). I have googled some details from my sqlnet.log file and landed on that topic http://www.developpez.net/forums/d95315/bases-donnees/oracle/ora-12154-data-environment-sous-visual-basic-6-a/ which hinted at parenthesis in the .exe path being the culprit. My folder containted parenthesis '(' and ')'. After removing the parenthesis things work ok. I am still quite interested if anyone happens to have a more "in-depth" explanation.

Comment: Strange... maybe the OS of the machine it runs from standalone is more picky about the folder names than your dev workstation's. Or maybe given that this is a VB6 app there might be some cases where it balks when trying to navigate folders with certain characters in the path. No idea but glad you found out why this was happening!

Comment: Not an OS difference problem, the bug was happening on my own dev machine (EXE only, not when running from the IDE). Should I mark this as closed ? It is so retarded that I would like to know the real truth (TM) behind it (ie bug or an actual documented limitation, etc.)

Comment: I'm working on something else atm and I probably won't be able to access that codebase again.
People can still answer this, but there will likely be no way to check the solution works.

(PS. I can't mark this as closed, can I ?)

Comment: You should write your answer, accept it and then mark as closed.